# Visual Basic 6 Negative Byte Check

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I'm converting a VB6 program to C#, and I came across the following block of code (b is a byte array from a string, lngLen is a length pointer we're initializing):

```
If UBound(b) <= 0 Then
    lngLen = UBound(b)
ElseIf UBound(b) >= 2 Then
    If b(UBound(b) - 2) >= 0 And b(UBound(b) - 1) = &HFE And b(UBound(b)) = &HFF Then
        lngLen = UBound(b) - 3
    Else
        lngLen = UBound(b)
    End If
Else
    lngLen = UBound(b)
End If
```

On line 4 I can tell that it's checking for a BOM in the last two characters of the byte array, but what does the first check for `b(UBound(b) - 2) >= 0` do? Isn't it impossible for a byte to be negative?

Comment: `Isn't it impossible for a byte to be negative?` - it is. This code was probably ported to VB6, too.

Comment: Or it may have been written by an inexperienced or overly cautious VB6 programmer. I doubt in this example that the extra check will impact execution time in a measurable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible for a VB6 byte to be negative. The values can only be 0-255 as [documented here in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28VS.60%29.aspx).

The check `b(UBound(b) - 2) >= 0` will always be `True` and can be removed from the VB6 code. The check does not need to be migrated to C#.